# VSCode TypeScript Plugin and workspaces API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, languageservice

I am writing a [TypeScript language plugin for GraphQL](https://github.com/divyenduz/ts-graphql-plugin) and I need to access the project root at [some places](https://github.com/divyenduz/ts-graphql-plugin/blob/master/src/graphql-language-service-proxy.ts#L45-L46). I want to use the [workspaces API](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Extension-Authoring:-Adopting-Multi-Root-Workspace-APIs) to make this workspace ready.

I tried including `vscode` directly and that doesn't work

- I get the error `vscode` not found
- I have to install `vscode` engine and that looks like the wrong API.

Is it possible to pass information like this from extension to language plugin or is there a way to access workspace API in language plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. TypeScript server plugins run in a separate process from normal VS Code extensions and cannot access the normal VS code api.

[This feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18604) would add a basic channel so that VS Code extensions to communicate with TS server plugins.

The other option that could work today is to open a communications pipe from your plugin to a vscode extension.

Comment: Is there any documentation on opening the communication pipe method?

Comment: Ah! I think it is basic IPC you refer to. Because both extension and TS server plugin have access to the filesystem.

Comment: Yes. Both can use node apis. It should work but I think you'd be the first to actually try so there may be some hidden challenges